# Create Main Menu Windows Phone MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am new in windows phone programming, and I am stuck when creating a main menu.
So, the basic is i want to display 5 categories using listbox. The category is static. So Am I doing this right or not? can i make more simple code than this? here's my code for now, using the WP Template from VS2012.

I really appreciate if anyone could help me understanding MVVM pattern,

**/Views/MainPage.xaml:**

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="-48,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Categories = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Categories { get; private set; }

    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        // Sample data; replace with real data
        this.Categories.Add(new ItemViewModel() { Category = "tourist attraction" });
        this.Categories.Add(new ItemViewModel() { Category = "hotel" });
        this.Categories.Add(new ItemViewModel() { Category = "restaurant" });
        this.Categories.Add(new ItemViewModel() { Category = "bars & nightlife" });
        this.Categories.Add(new ItemViewModel() { Category = "shopping centre" });

        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

**/Views/ItemViewModel.cs**

```
public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _category;
    public string Category
    {
        get
        {
            return _category;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _category)
            {
                _category = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Category");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Isn't it working?

Comment: @Daniel : Yeah it's working, the problem is, am I doing this right or not? is this what they called with MVVM pattern? cause I just simply change it all from the template. I was thinking, is there any way to simple this code to create a static main menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Menu is static, I recommend an custom user control with the viewmodel you showed.

I don't agree with the ItemViewModel, because it doesn't seam a view model, its seams a model it should be only be an INotifyPropertyChanged implementation (or any other base model class that you have). 
Remember the view model should work as a container of data and related data operations, not be the data itself.

Like Daniel stated there isn't anything wrong with your code, this solution is as good as any other, MVVM is an architectural pattern, its better sometimes to have code that you can read and understand than strict MVVM code that you can't understand

Comment: Thanks for recommend me using custom user control. I agree that better to have a code that I can read, but I want to learn MVVM, do you have any good resources to learn MVVM for Windows Phone @DVD?

Comment: There are many but you can check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848247.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx (this one for WPF but the concepts are there)